# A multiple port hosting solution for Node.js application

Tags: node.js, tcp, azure, amazon-web-services, nodejitsu

I have developed a Node.js application which receives data from TCP and at the same time makes the data available to a Socket.io port.

The principle of the application is to collect sensor data and make it available on the browsers. This application requires 2 ports (1 for TCP (net) and 1 for socket.io).

I have tried various cloud hosting solution for Node.js including Nodejitsu, AppFog (AWS), Azure, but all of these provide a single port through an environment variable process.env.port.

Is there any alternative other than dedicated hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Azure should be able to handle this fine in a Cloud Service (but not in a Web Site). The command-line tools won't do a great job of helping you... you'll have to take a look at `ServiceDefinition.csdef` and add the appropriate endpoints there. You'll want to use a worker role, not a web role.

I hope that gets you started.

Comment: And there's a tutorial on the Windows Azure website showing you how to host socket.io on a different port: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/app-using-socketio/

Comment: Thanks smarx! This seems to working for now. Will make sure on final deployment. :)